# How to accelerate the nearest neighbor interpolation of vectors in 3D?

Tags: python

I have a vector field defined on grid like this
[image: for example, https://elektromagnetisme.no/blog/page/5/]

And I have a bunch of points. `(x, y, z)` are the coordinates of these points. I wan to find the vector values on these points. I use nearest neighbor interpolation to calculate the vectors on these points, but I have many points (~4M) here, and my code runs slow. Here is my example code:

```
from scipy.ndimage import map_coordinates
import numpy as np

# examples of vectors `v` on grid 
vx=np.random.randn(500,100,100)
vy=np.random.randn(500,100,100)
vz=np.random.randn(500,100,100)

# examples of locations `p`
x=np.random.rand(4000000)*500
y=np.random.rand(4000000)*100
z=np.random.rand(4000000)*100

# my solution at the moment
coords=np.array([x,y,z])

out = np.zeros((3, coords.shape[1]))
out[0]= map_coordinates(vx, coords, order=0)
out[1]= map_coordinates(vy, coords, order=0)
out[2]= map_coordinates(vz, coords, order=0)
```

Any idea to accelerate the nearest neighbor interpolation in 3D?

Comment: Sorry if this is dodging the question a little, but could you not define the vector field of a point as a function? A mathematical vector field is continuous. Anyway, rather than equally distribute vectors throughout space, could you define a function which produces a vector, given your (x,y,z)? In this toy example, it would be def vec(x,y,z): return(random.randn(500,100,100)).

Comment: @Alan I think I did not define my vector field clearly. So vector field is not defined by (x, y, z), it is defined in the 3D space. I only know its values on grid (or cartesian grid). (x, y, z) are some random points in the 3D space, and I want to get the values of vector field on these points, and in this case, I choose to use the nearest neighbor to calculate it.